# How do I fix Mac Safari highlighted find text that is scrambled?

Tags: safari

When doing a "Find" (on page) within Mac Safari, the highlighted text is initially scrambled (jumbled or garbled).

[image]

Is anyone aware of a solution? I'm using 10.0.2 and macOS 10.12.2.

Comment: You really need to provide more info. As a minimum, the version of Safari and version of macOS would be good. Also, does this happen with any content you open with Safari? Or just particular types of content or particular websites?

Comment: Thanks, good suggestions. I added version numbers and will look into the other info.